# Comparing geodesics on a hypersphere

Tags: metric-spaces, geodesic, noneuclidean-geometry

#### Background:

In Euclidean space, a simple and easy to compute distance metric between two vectors $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$, is the [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) $ \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v} / |\mathbf{u}| |\mathbf{v}| $. On an intuitive level, it's nice since measures the angle between the two vectors.

#### Question:

I have two geodesics on a hypersphere $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}$. Since they are on a hypersphere, the geodesics take the form of a [great circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle). Is there an easy to compute distance metric that can compare the similarity between two great circles in high-dimensional space?

#### Current Attempts:

The geodesics that I'm using are found using [Slerp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp), thus they are realized by a finite set of points. Hence I'm approximating the true geodesic by a series of small line segments. My distance measure is then the average *cosine similarity* for the two paths by taking equal steps along the parametrization.

Comment: How about the angle between the two geodesics at their point(s) of intersection?

Comment: @AmitaiYuval there is absolutely no guarantee that they intersect, in fact most of them don't.

Comment: Of course, in high dimension they need not intersect. How about the usual distance between two (compact) disjoint sets then?

Comment: @AmitaiYuval maybe I misunderstood your comment, but I'm not interested in the distance _between_ the two sets, rather I'm looking to see if the two paths moving along the hypercoordinates in the same way. I know that this is vague (hence the question), but imagine a normal two sphere: you can parameterize it by spherical coordinates $\phi, \psi$. Two arcs would be 100% similar if the change along the parametrized paths would invoke approximately the same change in these coordinates.